# How can I schedule a script in pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, pythonanywhere, cron-task

I have a python script that is reliant of 2 Excel files that I have stored locally. How can I schedule this task in pythonanywhere.com? I know I can upload them to the website, but I do not know how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your excel files have to be available to your script running on PythonAnywhere, so you need to upload them or make them available over the network. To set your task go to the Tasks tab on your Dashboard. From there you can set up tasks to run daily at a particular time of day, or — for paying customers — hourly at a particular number of minutes past the hour. Take look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ScheduledTasks/